# How to understand this EBNF Pascal Definition

Tags: pascal, ebnf

I'm implementing a Pascal parser from this [EBNF defintion](http://www.fit.vutbr.cz/study/courses/APR/public/ebnf.html#variable). There is something I don't understand in the following specifications:

```
variable
   entire-variable | component-variable | referenced-variable 

entire-variable
   variable-identifier | field-identifier

component-variable
   indexed-variable | field-designator | file-buffer

field-designator
   record-variable "." field-identifier
```

Assume we want to apply the `variable` production on `a.b[0]`. Since `a` conforms to the `entire-variable` production, this will prevent `component-variable` from detecting the `field-designator` `a.b` and therefore the `.` following `a` will stop the parser.

Comment: I don't have the Pascal spec in front of me but I can make a few observations. When the parser sees 'a', it should already know what 'a' is defined as. Also the parser can look-ahead and see the '.'.

Comment: Readers of this question might also want to take a look at [How to define Pascal variables in PetitParser](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54207918/4081336)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since EBNF doesn't have ordered choices, the longest match is often used to determine which rules apply.

Comment: Thanks Uran. This makes sense. I didn't know that the choices have no order.