# How to define Pascal variables in PetitParser

Tags: smalltalk, petitparser

Here is the (simplified) EBNF section I'm trying to implement in PetitParser:

```
variable :: component / identifier
component :: indexed / field
indexed :: variable , $[ , blah , $]
field :: variable , $. , identifier
```

What I did was to add all these productions (except `identifier`) as ivars of my subclass of `PPCompositeParser` and define the corresponding methods as follows:

```
variable
  ^component / self identifier

component
  ^indexed / field

identifier
  ^(#letter asParser, (#word asParser) star) flatten

indexed
  ^variable , $[ asParser, #digit asParser, $] asParser

field
  ^variable , $. asParser, self identifier

start
  ^variable
```

Finally, I created a new instance of my parser and sent to it the message `parse: 'a.b[0]'`.

**The problem:** I get a stack overflow.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that your grammar is *left recursive*. PetitParser uses a top-down greedy algorithm to parse the input string. If you follow the steps, you'll see that it goes from `start` then `variable -> component -> indexed -> variable`. This is becomes a loop that gets executed infinitely without consuming *any* input, and is the reason of the stack overflow (that is the left-recursiveness in practice).

The trick to solve the situation is to rewrite the parser by adding intermediate steps to avoid left-recursing. The basic idea is that the rewritten version will consume at least one character in each cycle. Let's start by simplifying a bit the parser refactoring the non-recursive parts of ´indexed´ and ´field´, and moving them to the bottom.

```
variable
  ^component, self identifier

component
  ^indexed / field

indexed
  ^variable, subscript

field
  ^variable, fieldName

start
  ^variable


subscript
    ^$[ asParser, #digit asParser, $] asParser

fieldName
    ^$. asParser, self identifier

identifier
  ^(#letter asParser, (#word asParser) star) flatten
```

Now you can more easily see (by following the loop) that if the recursion in `variable` is to end, an identifier has to be found at the beginning. That's the only way to start, and then comes more input (or ends). Let's call that second part `variable'`:

```
variable
    ^self identifier, variable'
```

now the `variable'` actually refers to something with the identifier consumed, and we can safely move the recusion from the left of `indexed` and `field` to the right in `variable'`:

```
variable'
    component', variable' / nil asParser

component'
    ^indexed' / field'

indexed'
    ^subscript

field'
    ^fieldName
```

I've written this answer without actually testing the code, but should be okish. The parser can be further simplified, I leave that as an excercise ;).

For more information on left-recursion elimination you can have a look at [left recursion elimination](http://www.csd.uwo.ca/~moreno/CS447/Lectures/Syntax.html/node8.html)

Comment: Many thanks melkyades. I think that the last production should read `field' ^fieldName`, shouldn't it?

Answer (score 7):

The grammar has a left recursion: `variable -> component -> indexed -> variable`. PetitParser uses [Parsing Expression Grammars (PEGs)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parsing_expression_grammar) that cannot handle left recursion. A PEG parser always takes the left option until it finds a match. In this case it will not find a match due to the left recursion. To make it work you need to first eliminate left recursion. Eliminating all left recursion could be more tricky as you will also get one through `field` after eliminating the first. For example, you can write the grammar as follows to make the left recursion more obvious:

```
variable = (variable , $[ , blah , $]) | (variable , $. , identifier) | identifier
```

If you have a left recursion like:

```
A  -> A a |  b
```

you can eliminate it like (e is an empty parser)

```
A  -> b A'
A' -> a A' | e
```

You'll need to apply this twice to get rid of the recursion.
Alternatively you can choose to simplify the grammar if you do not want to parse all possible combinations of identifiers.

Comment: Excellent answer. Thanks a lot.

Comment: It is not easy for me to decide between accepting your answer or @melkyades's. I'll accept theirs because it includes working code. Thanks again for your answer, it's been very useful too.